# Remove ObjectId from mongodb document serialized to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, reactjs, mongodb, parsing

I'm having a bit of an issue here. I am getting all my products from a mongodb collection with this function:

```
public async Task<string> getAllProducts()
        {
            List<string> all = new List<string>();

            var document = await getCollection("produits").Find(new BsonDocument()).ToCursorAsync();
            foreach (var doc in document.ToEnumerable())
            {
                var res = doc.ToJson();
                all.Add(res);
            }
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(all);
        }
```

and it returns a JSON that looks like this to my react front end.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e49bdf5f040e808847a17d7"), 
"email" : "example@gmail.com", 
"quantite" : 1, 
"matricule" : 1}
```

problem is i cant parse this in my javascript because of this : **ObjectId("5e49bdf5f040e808847a17d7")**

Of course I could do some string magic before I parse it, but id rather it be corrected on the server side. So is there a way I can get rid of this problem and get a result like this?

```
{ "_id" : "5e49bdf5f040e808847a17d7", 
    "email" : "example@gmail.com", 
    "quantite" : 1, 
    "matricule" : 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed by creating a class for the mongodb object.**

```
public class Product
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int matricule { get; set; }
    public int quantite { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public float prix { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

**get them and deserialize with BsonSerializer :**

```
public async Task<List<Product>> getAllProducts(){
    var collection = await getCollection("produits").Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
    List<Product> all = new List<Product>();
    foreach(var doc in collection){
        all.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Product>(doc));
    }
    return all;
}
```

**return them on request :**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> ShowProductsAsync()
{
    MongodbModel model = new MongodbModel();
    var products = await model.getAllProducts();
    Console.WriteLine(products);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

give this a try. it will serialize string ids without objectid stuff.

```cs
    public static async Task<string> getAllProducts()
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<object>("produits");

        var all = new List<object>();

        using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync("{}"))
        {
            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                foreach (var doc in cursor.Current.ToArray())
                {
                    all.Add(doc);
                }
            }
        }

        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(all);
    }
```

Comment: there you go! yup that fixed the issue, thank you so much.

Comment: but it does come with a slight hitch , each key is in its own json, instead of one with all the keys, but theres a work around for that thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
string GetAllProduits(){
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("produits");
    var project = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id");
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
    var rlt=collection.Find(filter).Project(project);
    return rlt.ToList().ToJson();
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you explain OP what you have done in this code.

Comment: LOL, excluding the _id is not an answer.