# Generating _id for MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We are using MongoDB C#.NET Driver to insert entry as below:

```
var JSON = "{ 'UserName': '" + "Roy" + "', 'PasswordHash' : '" + "123" + "' }";

            var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(JSON);

            await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
```

In MongoDb, it goes with

```
_id:ObjectId("5e54f9ea045dba534831a1a2")
```

Which gives issues when retrieved and tried to convert into json.
How can I set the _id from C# code itself?

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264331/remove-objectid-from-mongodb-document-serialized-to-jsonin-c-sharp

Comment: _id in mongo is simply a hex string, could you just create a uuid / hex in c#, assign it to your domain then save it? not sure how good practice this is though. also why are you inserting json directly into your db and not creating a dedicated domain object?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` is always generated on a client side - the driver does that behind the scenes when you run `.Insert()` or `.Save()`. You can do that manually by running:

```
document["_id"] = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
```

Comment: I tried that but the below got inserted:
_id:ObjectId("5e60abdd89b5880a48464df0")

We want only _id:"5e60abdd89b5880a48464df0" to go into the MongoDb.

Comment: The solution in my case was : document["_id"] = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString(); If you could put it as the answer, I would mark it as the answer.